# Приём длинных строк на Arduino UNO через Serial, и отправка через MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, arduino, ethernet

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста. 
Имеется Arduino Uno 
В неё залит скетч который использует библиотеки

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>
```

И при получении строки по Serial , ретранслирует её в виде MySQL запроса 
вот так вот :

```
if (Serial.available()) {
    String str;
    // Считываем данные
    str = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    String val = "INSERT";
    if (str.lastIndexOf(val) > -1) {
        Serial.println("Execute MySQL request");    
        MySQL_Cursor *cur_mem = new MySQL_Cursor(&conn);
        char INSERT_SQL[str.length()];
        str.toCharArray(INSERT_SQL,str.length());
        cur_mem->execute(INSERT_SQL);
        delete cur_mem;    
    }
    // Возвращаем данные в порт
    Serial.println(str);    
  }
```

вот это написано после компиляции скейча

```
Скетч использует 18634 байт (57%) памяти устройства. Всего доступно 32256 байт.
Глобальные переменные используют 1089 байт (53%) динамической памяти, оставляя 959 байт для локальных переменных. Максимум: 2048 байт.
```

проблемы начинаются как только длинна строки пришедшая по Serial , превышает некое значение, к примеру

> INSERT INTO
>   parsersystem.Procedures(id,platform,jsonData,ts_create,ts_update)
>   VALUE
>   (412978,'roseltorg','1234567890123456789012345678901234567890',null,null);

еще выполняется , но если добавить еще хотя-бы некое количество символов то Arduino переглючивает (виснет на строке char INSERT_SQL[str.length()]), она переглючивает начинает запускать цикл Setup заново и даже не запускается нормально уже, не получает IP, не подключается к серверу MySQL.

я так понимаю что у неё не хватает памяти на создания массива char INSERT_SQL[str.length()]; , но КАК ? как такое может быть .. :( я не верю что это нельзя победить.

Comment: Может использовать параметрические запросы? `INSERT INTO parsersystem.Procedures(id,platform,jsonData,ts_create,ts_update) VALUE (?,?,?,?,?)`

Comment: в смысле ? это как ?

Comment: это запрос - отдельно, параметры - отдельно.

Comment: Вот https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html пример для даной версии SQL

Comment: так в любом случае это будет сделано до формирования итогового массива INSERT_SQL[str.length()], и при его инициализации она упадёт, или я что-то не так понимаю ?

Comment: Нет, параметрический запрос сделан что б разгрузить основной sql и убрать разные проблемы с конкатенацией "неразрешенных" символов. Если оно праильно реализовано - то поможет.

Comment: не помогло, я убрал вообще всё что связано с MySQL, оставил просто приём строки и отправку её назадв Serial , при определённой длинне строки Arduino виснет :(

Comment: Нет. Передавайте параметры отдельно, запрос отдельно. Используйте *параметрический запрос*. Изучите чем  *параметрический запрос* или *параметризованый* отличается от обычного.

Comment: Строка `char INSERT_SQL[str.length()];` не являтся валидной в C++, так как размер массива должен быть константой времени компиляции. Кроме того, непонятно зачем вы перекладываете байты из строки в буфер на стеке. если класс `String` не дает доступа к своему буфера напрямую, то складывайте данные прямо в массив байт и не транжирте память.

Answer (score 1):

Вы упираетесь в размер стека. Всей памяти всего то 2к (если я не ошибаюсь), а размер стека в районе 128-160 байт. Строка `char INSERT_SQL[str.length()];` выделяет память на стеке и размер этой строки очень близок к размеру стека.

Что делать? Дорожить каждым байтом. Или перейти на другую платформу, где чуть больше памяти.

Answer (score 0):

После оптимизации кода, с переходом к прямому чтению в буфер проблема на платформе Uno не решилась, но стало ясно что нужно

привожу код

```
const int numChars = 5000;
char receivedChars[numChars];   // an array to store the received data
boolean newData = false;

void recvWithEndMarker() {
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char endMarker = '\n';
    char rc;

    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = Serial.read();
        if (rc != endMarker) {
            receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
            ndx++;
            if (ndx >= numChars) {
                ndx = numChars - 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
            ndx = 0;
            newData = true;
        }
    } }

void showNewData() {
    if (newData == true) {
        Serial.println(receivedChars);
        Serial.println("Execute MySQL request");
        MySQL_Cursor *cur_mem = new MySQL_Cursor(&conn);
        cur_mem->execute(receivedChars);
        delete cur_mem;    
        newData = false;
    }
```

Единственный разумный выход для прямого выполнения больших SQL запросов это выходит купить Arduino Mega , с 256 или больше ОЗУ, на ней при char receivedChars[5000]; остаётся еще 2000 байт свободной памяти.

Опробовал на Wemos D1 mini , у него 128кб , теперь с памятью всё нормально но при выполнении SQL запроса процесс длится где-то минуты 2.
при запросе 1400 байт.